# JPA mapping: OneToMany (bidirectional) relationship does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I can't get my bidirectional relationship to work.
After reading hours of tutorials I have this classes:

**SourceSystems.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "source_systems")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class SourceSystems implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
private String url;

@Column(name = "identifier")
private String identifier;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "trading_activated", nullable = false)
private boolean tradingActivated;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="sourceSystems", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Currency> currencies;

// getters and setters
```

**Currency.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Currency implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "identifier", nullable = false)
private String identifier;

@Column(name = "currency_ext_id")
private String currencyExtId;

@Column(name = "disabled")
private Boolean disabled;

@Column(name = "date_added")
private ZonedDateTime dateAdded;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="source_systems_id")
private SourceSystems sourceSystems;
```

**One** SourceSystem has **n** Currencies. 
My goal is that I get a list of SourceSystems, and in each source system its currencies in the currencies list.

When I call a

```
sourceSystemsRepository.findAll();
```

It gives me back a list of source sstems, but its currencies is null. I also tried it over a join in the repository like this:

```
@Query("select source_systems from SourceSystems source_systems inner join source_systems.currencies currs where source_systems.tradingActivated = true")
List<SourceSystems> findAllActiveSourceSystemsWithCurrencies();
```

That one returned me something really strange:
[image: It duplicates the Source System objects by the number of the currencies]

It gives me back a set of SourceSystems, but they're duplicated as many times as I have currencies for the sourceSystem. But, inside of the SourceSystem, the currencies List is null.

Regarding the invocation exception: I regenerated  the toString method several times, without success.

I assume there's something wrong with the query in the repository.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)` is creating this issue 
   Pls read [hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-readonly) for more details 
   Try removing it and try again as you have already specified FetchType.EAGER should work fine.
2. **That one returned me something really strange:**  => It's obvious you are doing an inner join so your parent table will be repeated 
   as many times as child table due to join.
   Just iterate over List currencies and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is probably the **lazy load** issue.

Try [`JOIN FETCH`](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/10/fetch-join-is-still-a-join/) to fetch your parent entity along with its child entities **eagerly**.

```
@Query("select source_systems from SourceSystems source_systems join fetch source_systems.currencies currs where source_systems.tradingActivated = true")
List<SourceSystems> findAllActiveSourceSystemsWithCurrencies();
```